# Background image does not render on server (nextjs)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJs. I want to apply a background image on the body and it should be rendered on the server-side.

Here is my code

Below is my App.js

```
import BodyStyle from '@components/Bodystyle';
return (
    <>
      <BodyStyle bgColor={`url("picture-url")`} />
<>);
```

Here is my BodyStyle.js

```
const BodyStyle = (props) => {
  const { bgColor } =
    props;
  return (
    <Head>
      <style>{`body { background: ${bgColor} no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;`}</style>
    </Head>
  );
```

The background is applied to the body but **not from SSR**

***But there is a twist*** if I just copy the code from `BodyStyles.js`  and paste in `app.js` the  background image renders fine on the server

Here is the example code of the App.js

```
import Head from 'next/head';

return (
  <Head>
        <style>{`body { background: url(${url}) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;`}</style>
      </Head> 
);
```

Attached screenshots
**Without background on SSR**
[image]

**With the background on SSR**
[image]

What could be an issue? Any help

Comment: I don't see `url(${url})` in your BodyStyle.js but I see it in App.js. Are you sure you copied it directly. Perhaps I'm missing something as I've never worked with Next

Comment: Since I am passing it as props ` bgColor={`url("picture-url")`}`

Comment: Are you sure that prop is being passed to your BodyStyle.js and if so don't you still need to implement it the same way you do in App.js?

Comment: try using <img> tag instead of <style>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its because you use to set bgcolor when there isn't any props yet try using it inside an useEffect or like this code:

```
const BodyStyle = ({bgColor}) => {

  return (
    <Head>
      <style>{`body { background: ${bgColor} no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;`}</style>
    </Head>
  );
```